# Why c# datagridview returns double of records?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview that I need to populate data from sql server.Here is the code.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);

                        //Set AutoGenerateColumns False
                        gfDataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

                        //Set Columns Count
                        gfDataGridView1.ColumnCount = 87;



                        gfDataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This code returns me 87 columns (first 87) with totally empty and 87 columns with real data from database.How can I avoid these 87 empty columns?

[image]

Comment: Is your DataTable having more columns than 3 ?

Comment: `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` means that you are trying to pass an index to an array that is invalid, i.e. outside the valid range. Try stepping through with a debugger to see on which line the error occurs.

Comment: Yes it has 87 columns.But in my sql statement I am selecting only 3 rows

Comment: @user1353519, in debug mode, just check Whether your datatable has more than 3 columns or not and you could solve it yourself.

Comment: Issue is with this  gfDataGridView1.DataSource = dt;.This line causes the error

Comment: @user1353519, undoubtedly that will cause an error because you have limited your datagridview to 3 columns and you might be binding the datatable having more than 3 columns.

Comment: In a previous comment you said the statement is returning 87 columns, but you're only trying to fill 3 columns.

Comment: I tried this. gfDataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;gfDataGridView1.ColumnCount =87;.Reason I have 87 columns in table.Then no error and it is working.But that will add 87 empty columns to datagridview and also showing 87 columns with data.

Comment: Well yes, that's exactly how it's supposed to work. If you only want 3 columns from `DataTable dt` then you will need to manually extract the columns, since you are autofilling it with all 87 columns with the line `sda.Fill(dt);`.

Comment: then how can I hide those empty columns? to explain you now I have 174 columns in datagridview.First 87 columns are empty and rest of the columns having exact data

Comment: Easiest way is to just reset `ColumnCount`: `gfDataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;` But of course first you will need to copy the values from the valid columns into the first 3.

Comment: Wait, something doesn't make sense. If your select statement specifies only 3 columns, why is it returning 87?

Comment: I changed my select statement as SELECT * FROM Customers.Also changed Autogeneratecolumns = true and columncount=87.Now as I said I am returning everything with 87 empty columns and 87 columns with data.Totally 174 columns in datagridview.

Comment: If you only need 3 columns in your data grid view, why not just *use the code you actually posted* to return only those 3 columns in question?

Comment: Actually I need to have all columns.Reason I need to make an option for customer where he can turn off them by selecting them.Just wanted to try with 3 columns first.But strange why exactly the same amount of columns returning to datagrid as empty.

Comment: Ok so it sounds like you have a different problem now; your query should only return 87 columns but it returns double that, and half the columns are empty. I would suggestion opening a new question for that.

Comment: This post is misleading, because the problem can't be reproduced with the code given. Please edit your original post to include your *actual code*, otherwise this question will be closed because the problem can't be reproduced as you've described it.

Comment: Yes I edited the code and correct the question.Thanks

Comment: Once you set true to AutoGenerateColumns, you don't need to set the ColumnCount.

Comment: Then the issue is when I remove ColumnCount I am getting this error on Program.cs page.An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.